# jQuery parent <li>

Tags: jquery, list

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">texT</a>
    <ul>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
```

**How to get direct `<li>` from `.menu`?**

`<li>` inside child `<ul>` should not be taken.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function:

```
var lis = ​$('.menu')​.children('li')​;
```

Comment: As opposed to $('.menu').find('li'), which would return ALL li elements underneath ul.menu regardless of depth.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('.menu > li')
```

I recommend taking a look at jQuery's [selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".menu > li")
```

Answer (score 1):

would this work?

```
$(".menu > li")
```